# Чем занят процессор, когда запущено приложение MFC?

Tags: windows, mfc

Если приложение ждёт действий пользователя (ну, к примеру, пока нажмут кнопку), в самом приложении выполняется какой либо код?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Конечно выполняется: главный поток заблокирован на вызове ожидания события из очереди. Периодически какие-то события происходят, приложения их обрабатывает и снова стаёт на блокировку внутри очереди.

Comment: Но во время блокировки КОД ПРИЛОЖЕНИЯ (заблокированного потока) не выполняется.